# Kendo UI Web Scheduler: In Monthly view mode, events are collapsed into "three points" bar

Tags: kendo-ui

In Monthly view mode (Kendo UI, Q3 2013 SP1 (version 2013.3.1316)), events are collapsed into "three points" bar, even if there is only one event in that day:

[image: Collapsed events in Monthly view]

The Scheduler widget is defined like the following:

```
<div id="scheduler" style="height:500px"></div>

$("#scheduler").kendoScheduler({
    editable: {
        confirmation: false
    },
    resources: ko.observable([
        {
            field: "displayMode",
            dataSource: [
                    { text: "Regular-Other-Future", value: 111, color: "#93D095" },
                    ...
            ]
        }
    ]),
    add: function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // Custom adding implementation
    },
    edit: function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // Custom editing implementation
    },
    remove: function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // Custom removing implementation
    },
    moveStart: function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // Prevent drag-and-drop
    },
    move: function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // Prevent drag-and-drop
    },
    moveEnd: function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // Prevent drag-and-drop
    },
    views: [{ type: "day", showWorkHours: true }, { type: "week", showWorkHours: true, selected: true }, "month", "agenda"],
    timezone: "Etc/UTC",
    date: new Date(),
    dataSource: self.dataSource // self.dataSource is KO observable, which is assigned later with kendo.data.SchedulerDataSource()
});
```

The most interesting thing is that some time ago the scheduler looked as the following:

[image: Looked before]

I may be wrong but what we changed was updated to 2013.3.1119. Now we use 2013.3.1316, but the issue is still active.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: We need to see your code because by default it works fine: http://demos.kendoui.com/web/scheduler/index.html

Comment: Hi Atanas! I've added additional info to the post about the issue context. Thank you for the replay!

Comment: Did you figure this out? Likely has to do with your eventHeight setting? I am having a similar problem. Please let me know if you figure out how to force eventHeight without having it collapse into the ... button.

Answer (score 0):

I used below code to re-size the event size during Month view:

```
dataBound: function (e) {                       
    $(e.sender.element).find(".k-resize-handle").remove();
    var events = $(e.sender.element).find(".k-event").height(65);
},
```